# List Items with Horizontal Spacing

Tags: lists, indentation, description

When I try to build list of companies with no bulletin. I get the output as below

[image]

Actually I want is correct spacing between the colon. Exactly like the below example. 
[image]

Can anyone help me out.? 
Thanks in advance.

Code Used:

```
\begin{description}
   \item[TCS:] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
   \item[InfoSys:] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
   \item[Wipro:] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
\end{description}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using. The effect you want isn't difficult to achieve, but there are lots of ways to it.

Comment: Why no use a `tabular` instead of a *list*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple `tabular` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l >{:\quad} l}
TCS & Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore \\
InfoSys & Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore \\
Wipro & Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

To fine-tune the amount of whitespace to the left and right of the colon, you could employ a header such as

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l >{\hspace{8pt}:\hspace{10pt}} l}
```

where `8pt` and `10pt` could be adjusted to your liking. (You didn't state explicitly *what* the "correct" space values are...)

Answer (score 4):

KOMA-Script's `labeling` list could be used for this. It is available in every KOMA-Script class (like `scrartcl` or `scrbook`) and can be used in other classes by loading the `scrextend` package.

The syntax is:

```
\begin{labeling}[<separator>]{<widest label>}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\begin{labeling}[\quad:\quad]{InfoSys}
   \item[TCS] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
   \item[InfoSys] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
   \item[Wipro] Jeddah,Kochi,Bangalore 
\end{labeling} 

\end{document}
```

[image]